# Execute shell command via PHP and get output with info on whether from stdout and stderr

Tags: php, bash, shell

I’d like to execute a shell command and have the output in an array such that:
(1) each line of the output is an element in the array
(2) the lines are “tagged” as whether from stdout or stderr

Something like:

```
╔═════════╦══════════════════╗
║ Line No ║ Stdout or stderr ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Line1   ║ Stdout           ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Line2   ║ Stdout           ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Line3   ║ Stderr           ║
╠═════════╬══════════════════╣
║ Line4   ║ Stdout           ║
╚═════════╩══════════════════╝
```

This is a table, but what I really meant was a multi-dimensional array where $thisarray[0], $thisarray[1] are rows.
I am assuming that the shell command executed will always generate a new line before it switches to either stderr or stdout.

This way, I'd be able to see which line belongs to which file descriptor, and be able to see it in context.

Is there any way to do this in PHP, with the shell exec commands or otherwise?

If this is not possible with PHP, I do not mind other technologies.

Comment: So the PHP script itself is writing some lines to STDOUT and some to STDERR?  Can you modify the PHP script?  If not you can use Bash redirection (I will post sample code when and if you clarify).  Additionally, are the lines sorted in any order?

Comment: Basically you can use `proc_open` and then listen to the `STDOUT` and `STDERR` streams and push the data into an array along with the info where it came from.

Answer (score 0):

If you take your string input with line breaks in it and run it through this:

```
$arr = explode(PHP_EOL, $output);
```

Then $arr will have your array with one item per $output line.

Comment: unfortunately missing the more important part about differentiating between stdout and stderr